# show table border oracle apex html region

Tags: oracle-apex

The following code is not showing table border in apex report.

```
Declare
   Cursor c_Group Is
             select DISTINCT
    PSGROUP
FROM LOG_PS_STATUS;
   Cursor c_Col(p_Group Varchar2) Is
             select DISTINCT
    SRNO,PSCOLUMN as PSCOLUMN
FROM LOG_PS_STATUS
WHERE PSGROUP =p_Group
ORDER BY SRNO;

Begin  

   For Rec_d In c_Group Loop
   Htp.p('<table  border: 1px solid>');   
      Htp.p('<tr><td colspan=75%><b>' || Rec_d.PSGROUP|| '</b></td></tr>');

     Htp.p('<tr>');
      For Rec_e In c_Col(Rec_d.PSGROUP) Loop
         Htp.p('<td>' || Rec_e.PSCOLUMN|| '</td>');
      End Loop;
For Rec_e In c_Col(Rec_d.PSGROUP) Loop
         Htp.p('<tr><td>' || Rec_e.srno|| '</td></tr>');
      End Loop;
     Htp.p('</tr>');
      Htp.p('</table>');
   End Loop;

End;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table displays no border because your HTML is invalid. If you want inline CSS you have to use the `style` attribute which would contain inline CSS declarations.

> `style="css-property:css-value;…"`
>
> **Description**
>
> In Cascading Style Sheets (CSS), a key feature is the cascade itself.
>   In the cascade, styles set at different levels take different levels
>   of importance, so a style that’s set in a globally linked style sheet
>   can be overridden by a style for the same class or id that’s included
>   in an embedded style sheet. The style attribute goes a level further,
>   to override styles set in linked or embedded style sheets.
>
> **However, the use of the style attribute is generally considered to be**
>   **a bad practice**, as it causes the presentation to become intrinsically
>   mixed with the content of the document—a practice that’s almost as bad
>   as using the font element to style text. One way in which you might
>   use inline styles is to debug CSS display issues (applying the style
>   at its lowest level in the cascade, and progressively moving higher up
>   the cascade until the problem is isolated). You should, therefore,
>   avoid using inline style attributes in your markup.

(*Source: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/style*)

However:

- why not just make a classic report where you break on the first column (group)?
- why not use an IR with control break?

Try to use apex to its fullest instead of htp.p calls - that's avoiding the strength of it: declarative. Consider the possibilities and boundaries of apex first.

Comment: I have to show data as group and values using pivot. Thats why I have used above approach.